# How do I create a route53 record set using the aws sdk for ruby?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

EC2 gives instances a new IP address when they're stopped then restarted, so I need to be able to automatically manage a route53 record set so that I can access things consistently. Sadly the documentation for the route53 portion of the sdk is not nearly as robust as it is for ec2 (understandably) and so I'm a bit stuck. From what I've seen so far, it seems like `change_resource_record_sets` ([link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/Route53/Client.html#change_resource_record_sets-instance_method)) is the way to go, but I'm confused as to what needs go into `:chages` since it mentions a `Change` object but fails to provide a link to a description of said object.

Here's what my code currently looks like for a creation:

```
r53.client.change_resource_record_sets(:hosted_zone_id => 'MY_ID', :change_batch => {
    :changes => 'I DONT KNOW WHAT GOES HERE',
    :action => 'CREATE',
    :resource_record_set => {
        :name => @instance.instance_name,
        :type => 'CNAME',
        :ttl => 330,
        :value => @instance.ip_address
}})
```

EDIT: Okay, since I haven't had any help either here or on the official forums I've been messing around with it myself. So it turns out that the documentation is just plain awful. All of the values are stored in a `Change` object, and not given there. So it actually looks more like this:

```
some_change = AWS::Route53::CreateRequest.new(@instance.instance_name,
                                             'CNAME',
                                             :ttl => 330,
                                             :resource_records => [
                                                 {:value => @instance.ip_address}
                                             ])

r53.client.change_resource_record_sets(:hosted_zone_id => 'MY_ZONE', :change_batch => {
    :changes => [some_change],
})
```

Answer (score 9):

The documentation is pretty poor, though it does contain a few examples.  I initially had the impression that it was necessary to create requests (and use the client object) per your solution, but there are alternatives.

An example of creating a record can be found in the [ResourceRecordSetCollection reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/Route53/ResourceRecordSetCollection.html), but it's only a little more concise than your answer:

```
rrsets = AWS::Route53::HostedZone.new(hosted_zone_id).rrsets
rrset = rrsets.create('foo.example.com.', 'A', :ttl => 300, :resource_records => [{:value => '127.0.0.1'}])
```

I wanted to update an existing record, and didn't have the hosted_zone_id to hand.  It took far too long to figure out how best to do this, so I'm offering the following example in the hope it saves someone else some time:

```
r53    = AWS::Route53.new
domain = "example.com."
fqdn   = "host." + domain
zone   = r53.hosted_zones.select { |z| z.name == domain }.first
rrset  = zone.rrsets[fqdn, 'A']
rrset.resource_records = [ { :value => "1.2.3.4" } ]
rrset.update
```

Note that that assumes you only have a single zone with that name in Route53.

Answer (score 6):

The method that zts posted seems to be a much better way of updating records. However, if you're updating an alias record then you have to use `DeleteRequest`/`CreateRequest` as the `alias_target` instance attribute on `ResourceRecordSet` seems to be readonly, even though the docs don't list it as so.

Here's one way to do it. Note that the hosted zone id for the alias target (`region` in the code below) should not be a personal zone ID, it is actually an encrypted region ID. This doesn't seem to be documented anywhere, and the only reference for these IDs that I could find was in the [source of the fog gem](https://github.com/fog/fog/blob/54071a3e227620d163cba2a33e41f6d33caf669a/lib/fog/aws/requests/dns/change_resource_record_sets.rb#L229).

Edit: [This has now moved](https://github.com/fog/fog-aws/blob/ff72924210a99e70db00d6aa84a69e9dca05d193/lib/fog/aws/requests/dns/change_resource_record_sets.rb#L261) to a separate module called fog-aws and is more up to date.

```
{
  "ap-northeast-1" => "Z2YN17T5R711GT",
  "ap-southeast-1" => "Z1WI8VXHPB1R38",
  "ap-southeast-2" => "Z2999QAZ9SRTIC",
  "eu-west-1"      => "Z3NF1Z3NOM5OY2",
  "eu-central-1"   => "Z215JYRZR1TBD5",
  "sa-east-1"      => "Z2ES78Y61JGQKS",
  "us-east-1"      => "Z3DZXE0Q79N41H",
  "us-west-1"      => "Z1M58G0W56PQJA",
  "us-west-2"      => "Z33MTJ483KN6FU",
}
```

And the code:

```
change_request = {
  hosted_zone_id: zone.id,
  change_batch: { changes: [] }
}

alias_target = {
  hosted_zone_id: region,
  evaluate_target_health: false
}

# Delete the record if it already exists
if rrset.exists?
  alias_target[:dns_name] = rrset.alias_target[:dns_name]
  delete_request = AWS::Route53::DeleteRequest.new(fqdn, 'A', alias_target: alias_target)

  change_request[:change_batch][:changes][0] = delete_request
  r53.client.change_resource_record_sets(change_request)
end

# Create the new record
alias_target[:dns_name] = new_alias
create_request = AWS::Route53::CreateRequest.new(fqdn, 'A', alias_target: alias_target)

change_request[:change_batch][:changes][0] = create_request
r53.client.change_resource_record_sets(change_request)
```

Answer (score 4):

I hacked it until it worked, and here are my results:

Don't look at the ruby route53 documentation for anything but method/object/attribute names. It is misleading, if not outright wrong. Instead, check out the rest documentation since the client just builds up a standard xml request anyway. My example of creating a simple record is as follows:

```
some_change = AWS::Route53::CreateRequest.new("foo.bar.com",
                                         'CNAME', # the type of the resource record set
                                         :ttl => 330, # The cache time to live for the current resource record set
                                         :resource_records => [
                                             {:value => "0.0.0.0"} # dependent on type
                                         ])

r53.client.change_resource_record_sets(:hosted_zone_id => 'MY_ZONE', :change_batch => {
    :changes => [some_change],
})
```

Answer (score 2):

I initially worked with what @slippery John did, but that proved problematic for spot instances that reclaim certain dns names often.
I found a solution I think is better, almost I identical to his:

```
some_change = AWS::Route53::ChangeRequest.new("UPSERT","foo.bar.com",
                                         'CNAME', # the type of the resource record set
                                         :ttl => 330, # The cache time to live for the current resource record set
                                         :resource_records => [
                                             {:value => "0.0.0.0"} # dependent on type
                                         ])

r53.client.change_resource_record_sets(:hosted_zone_id => 'MY_ZONE', :change_batch => {
    :changes => [some_change],
})
```

it is intentionally copied from his solution with a slight modification.

Answer (score 0):

For aws-sdk v2 it is like this:

```
[72] pry(main)> r53 = Aws::Route53::Client.new
[73] pry(main)> change
=> {:action=>"UPSERT",
 :resource_record_set=>
  {:name=>"myhost.example.com",
   :resource_records=>[{:value=>"192.0.2.44"}],
   :ttl=>60,
   :type=>"A"}}
[44] pry(main)> res = r53.change_resource_record_sets(hosted_zone_id: my_zone_id, change_batch: {changes: [change]})
=> #<struct Aws::Route53::Types::ChangeResourceRecordSetsResponse
 change_info=
  #<struct Aws::Route53::Types::ChangeInfo
   id="/change/C02195391TWJO1GT9KVRV",
   status="PENDING",
   submitted_at=2020-11-03 21:39:09.41 UTC,
   comment=nil>>
```

For more info see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v2/api/Aws/Route53/Client.html#change_resource_record_sets-instance_method